# Как переопределить класс главной формы в Delphi (Embarcadero)

Tags: ооп, delphi, embarcadero

Есть задача: всем формам проекта (включая главную) сделать запуск некоторой процедуры на создание (onCreate).
Я решил создать свой класс TBaseForm(TForm), в котором переопределить конструктор:

```
type
  TBaseForm = class(TForm)
  constructor create(AOwner: TComponent);
end;

constructor TBaseForm.create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  //Что то делаю
end;
```

В файле проекта dpr я ничего не меняю:

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TfmMain, fmMain);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

В модуле главной формы пишу:

```
type
  TfmMain = class(TBaseForm)
```

Я ставлю прерывание в отладчике в конструкторе класса TBaseForm и почему-то туда не попадаю.
Почему? И как правильно оформить такую схему? Как сделать так чтобы абсолютно все формы проекта выполняли какую то определенную процедуру?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно правильно объявить конструктор (и компилятор, между прочим, сообщает об этом в варнинге):

```
type
  TBaseForm = class(TForm)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;
```